# If upgraded from laravel 5.5 to 5.8 passport not generating token on oauth/token url

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am not getting token on oauth/token this url after upgrading my laravel version from 5.5 to 5.8. Please suggest something.

Comment: Did you upgrade in one attempt? I think you should probably try to upgrade at least to 5.7 first. Also follow the Laravel guid lines for upgrading and review release notes for 5.6 - 5.8 versions. I know the authentication part has changed in recent versions.

Comment: soved the issue thankx for suggestion il see to it next time..

Answer (score 0):

Solved : You have to upgrade your passport to newest version, i.e ^7.0 on your composer.json and then update your composer with composer update.